# How to query multiple table names in sqlalchemy at once?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, sqlalchemy

I have a list of tables in a column of a csv that I have read in as a dataframe into pandas like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/tablenames')
```

tablenames csv looks like this:

```
tablenames
 table1
 table2
```

The connection to the db and iterating through the dataframe is created like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('~/tablenames')

engine = create_engine('connection_string')


 for index,row in df.iterrows():
        df['column_count'] = pd.read_sql_query("select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '%s'"%row['table_name'],con=engine)
        df['row_count'] = pd.read_sql_query("select count(*) from %s"%row['table_name'],con=engine)
```

The above loop is only getting the first tables data and is only executing the query for that first table in the dataframe. What am I doing wrong where the query is not executing for the rest of the table names in the dataframe?

I am not getting any error messages. If it helps I am connecting to a postgres db.

edit:

```
 count
0     45
   count
0     89
   count
0     36
   count
0     17
   count
0     12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop to

```
 #also here add .iloc[0]
 for index,row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[index,'column_count'] = pd.read_sql_query("select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '%s'"%row['table_name'],con=engine).iloc[0]
        df.loc[index,'row_count'] = pd.read_sql_query("select count(*) from %s"%row['table_name'],con=engine).iloc[0]
```

---

Update

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     updatedf=pd.read_sql_query("select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '%s'"%row['table_name'],con=engine)   
     df.loc[index,'column_count'] = updatedf.shape[1]
     df.loc[index,'row_count'] = updatedf.shape[0]
```

Comment: I tried your line, but your code is not even retrieving the first table and not generating any errors.

Comment: @RustyShackleford ummm wired , can you print what you have `pd.read_sql_query("select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '%s'"%row['table_name'],con=engine)`

Comment: very weird, when I print that line I get this ` count
0     45
   count
0     89
   count
0     36
   count
0     17
   count
0     12`

As notice I am getting all the row counts, the index is not changing so the data keeps getting overridden. I added formatted version of the print in the edit

Comment: @RustyShackleford is the update one solve the problem?

Comment: its closer, column_count is and row_count need to be switched but after switching the row_count is all the same

Comment: @RustyShackleford sry, Without any data , that is best I can do .

Comment: I just realized the row count is wrong because the query is not there in your code, the column code is right

Comment: @RustyShackleford but in my update method , I query the whole df , then , df.shape will return the columns and row length

Answer (score -1):

Try pandas concat

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# glob.glob('table*.csv') - returns List[str]
# for f in glob.glob() - returns a List[DataFrames]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob('table*.csv')], ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: I am not understanding why we are using concat. However I tried your line of code, and since its a singular csv there is nothing to concat.